# Что означает ! перед function?

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function main() {
 !function () { code }()
}
main();
```

встретил в js файле такую функцию, что означает ! перед function подскажите

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

Comment: В данном виде код, конечно же, некорректен. В общем же случае `!` может использоваться для того, чтобы компилятор воспринял функцию не как function declaration, а как function expression. Это может быть нужно, например, для того, чтобы сразу же на месте ее и вызвать (IIFE), но, опять же, в приведенном вами примере и этого не происходит.

Comment: @peter
вот оригинальный код
function main() {
 !function () {
  code
 }()
}
main();